# parse xml url in iphone

Tags: xml, parsing

I am quite new to xml parse by iPhone..

please help me how can i get all image string of all deals. please see xml:

< DealXml>

< DealId>254 < /DealId>

< Image>

< string>
http//offchi.com/Content/Images/Deals/634720181245941250634662123899446563prp01.jpg
< /string>

< string>
http//offchi.com/Content/Images/Deals/634720181245941250634662123899446563prp02.jpg
< /string>

< string>
http//offchi.com/Content/Images/Deals/634720181245941250634662123899446563prp03.jpg
< /string>

< /Image>

< /DealXml>

< DealXml>

....

< /DealXml>

Answer (score 0):

First you need to decide on a parsing library, this article might help you:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project

I would recommend using one that supports xpath which will allow you to retrieve your images using an expression such as:

```
//Image/string
```

More info about xpath here [Xpath W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/)

Hope this helps